# "Permission denied" error when writing to a file, but only if it does not exist yet

Tags: c, file-io, permissions, posix, system-calls

I generally don't like asking "what's wrong with my code" questions, but this is my last hope.

I'm doing a project in which I have to write to files, and I'm trying to do it using system calls (Linux). So I'm using `unistd.h`, which provides the functions: `int open( char* filename, int flags, int mode )` and `int write( int fd, void* ptr, int numbytes )`. I use `write` all the time with no problem, but that's normally with the standard out and standard error file descriptors.

So I use this code to open the file:

```
int flags = O_WRONLY;
if( !exists( "testfile2.txt" ) ) {
    flags |= O_CREAT;
}
int mode = S_IROTH | S_IWOTH | S_IXOTH;
int filedesc = open( "testfile2.txt", flags, mode );
```

And then this line to write to the file:

```
int written = write(filedesc, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    strlen("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ) );
```

And finally, I close the file with this:

```
int closed = close( filedesc );
```

The problem is that when I try to write to the file when it didn't already exist, I get a message saying "permission denied". When I open it in vi and ignore the permissions, the file appears to be empty. However, if the file existed initially, it writes to it and I can read it just fine. Does anyone have any clue what's going wrong or if I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no need to check if the file exists.  Just add O_CREAT to flags--it has no effect if the file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open), `O_CREAT` uses the permission bits only if the file does not exists. You pass a permission mask of 007, denying "owner" and "group" all rights on the file. Use at least `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR` in the mode flags:

```
x@y:~/tmp$ touch test
x@y:~/tmp$ cat test
x@y:~/tmp$ chmod 007 test
x@y:~/tmp$ cat test
cat: test: Permission denied
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I feel silly, but you live and you learn.

Comment: You're welcome. I wasn't aware of that behavior in POSIX ... until a couple of minutes ago :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the mode to give permission to others, but not yourself.  Just set mode = 0777.

Comment: And remember that the mode will be modified by your umask, which defaults to 0022.

Comment: Under what conditions does that happen?

Comment: @phoenixheart6.  I do not understand your question.  If you create a file, the mode is always modified by the umask.